# Kubernetes dependent pods - how to trigger restart of dependent pod?

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I have 2 separate pods that make up one application instance (1 tomcat web server, and 1 postgres db). When the database pod is restarted, the application does not make a new connection to the new database pod, and is stuck in a state where the web server is inaccessible (trying to stay connected to a pod that does not exist?). How can I trigger a restart of the application server once the database pod is restarted (this can be for a host shutdown, maintenance, or any other reason)?

I am currently using init containers to make the initial connection the the database server (if the db is not up, do not start the app pod), this works fine when stating up the pods both manually/initially. But when the app is already running, it seems that it does not make the new connection on the fly.

Comment: How is the connection to db implemented? You can configure livenessprobe in tomcat pod to check if the db is up. If the livenessprobe fails the pod will be restarted. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-liveness-http-request

Comment: The app is connecting to the db through a ClusterIP service. The DB is in a separate pod on (possibly) a separate node.

Comment: The issue I am having is that the app disconnects from the database (we can see the postgres errors in "kubectl logs" of the app container) but does not restart itself, or attempt to reconnect to the database once failed out. We need a way to realize the app is in a failed state due to the db server going down/restarting (even when there are no k8s errors until digging deeper into the app logs)

Comment: You can try to set up liveness probe on web server where it check if website (where connection to db is necessary) is up and if it is not you, pod will be restarted.